# Angular 6-*ngFor with custom sorting and pagination-how to apply

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-pipe

I am having a table bind with *ngFor and want to apply sorting using custom pipe and pagination using ngx-pagination.What is the best practice to apply -a)sorting then pagination or b)pagination followed by sorting to get correct result.

```
<div class="pagination-group">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }|sortBy: column: columnClicked "> ... </li>
  </ul>

  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Comment: Is what you have now not working?? or are you just asking for best practices??

Comment: Try prime ng data table

Comment: Try to write them inside brackets:
<li *ngFor="let item of (collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }) | sortBy: column: columnClicked "> ... </li>

Comment: best practice only.its working.